# Which way should I follow to set system ID

Tags: ios, swift

I have global array named newSystems which contains objects of following System class:

```
class System: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var systemView: UIViewController?
    private let _systemName: String!
    private let _systemType: String!
    let _systemImplForCustomerID: String!

    init(name: String, type: String, systemID: String) {
        _systemName = name
        _systemType = type
        _systemImplForCustomerID = systemID
        systemView = System.setSystemView(_systemType: type)
    }

    private static func setSystemView(_systemType: String) -> UIViewController{
        var sysView: UIViewController!
        switch _systemType {
        case "Room":
            sysView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View1") as! UINavigationController
        case "Kitchen":
            sysView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View2") as! KitchenVC    
        default:
            break;
        }
        return sysView
    }

}
```

Now in `TabBarController` I am assigning the `systemView` property to `viewControllers` array:

```
for system in newSystems {
   if let newView = system.systemView {
      self.viewControllers?.insert(newView, at: 0)
   }
}
```

So now `TabBarController` shows 2 items in `tabBar`, both are accessible and works fine. 
But now in Room I would like to use `_systemImplForCustomerID`

Example of RoomVC:

```
class RoomVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!       

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = UICollectionViewCell()
        *** Here I need the _systemImplForCustomerID ***
        return cell
    }
```

My question is how should I get `_systemImplForCustomerID` property? Or which way should I follow to have it there. As temporary solution I have created function which filtering global array `newSystems` and works fine, but is it correct solution?

```
func findCustomerSystemImplID(view: UIViewController) -> String? {
    var id: String?
    let currentSystem = newSystems { $0.systemView?.view.accessibilityIdentifier == view.view.accessibilityIdentifier }
    if let sysID = currentSystem.first?.customerSystemImplID {
        id = sysID
    }
    return id
}
```

Comment: It would probably benefit us if you could expand a bit more on what you mean by "system".

Comment: @user137791 edited

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "But now I need to use in RoomVC, the identifier which has been received. The same in KitchenVC etc."

Comment: @Sam tried to ask the same in another way

Comment: Please explain "on the viewWillAppear receiving system assigned to the logged user". What is a "receiving system"?

Comment: @ryantxr in viewWillAppear method, app is calling for the api which gives in response JSON with system or systems which are assigned to the user who is currently logged to the app. System is a data which are used to build object System

Comment: Sorry, that this has been going on for a while. But it would be awesome if you could share some code with us.

Comment: @Sam I made it more clear I hope now

Comment: I think I have a solution for you. Not sure how to remove this question from hold.

change the `private static func setSystemView(_systemType: String)` to accept two arguments, 

`setSystemView(_systemType: String, _systemImplForCustomerID: String)`

and now pass the _systemImplForCustomerID as an argument, in the initializer of system.

You'll need to create a `_systemImplForCustomerID` variable in RoomVC.

Now, in `setSystemView` method, extract the rootVeiwController from the navigation controller in the `Room` case and cast it as a RoomVC.

Assign the newly created var here.

Comment: @Sam `if let rootVC = sysView.navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? RoomVC {
                rootVC._systemImplForCustomerID = _systemImplForCustomerID
            }` if I do this way, getting nil in RoomVC and `rootVC` is nil also

Comment: I was assuming that, RoomVC is the rootViewController of the UINavigationController. Was I correct?

Comment: Yes, you were right. When debugging, in line `if let rootVC = sysView.navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? RoomVC` the `rootVC` has type as we expect.. but not going inside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164000/discussion-between-sam-and-micgal).